# How to manage order of attributes on configurable products

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, magento-1, attribute-set

If i have an attribute set witch has attributes "Color" and "Size". How do I choose the variant order on the quick created child products?

Let's say the child product is getting a SKU like this: `shoe-42-red`

How do I change the order of attributes, so the child product is created like this: `shoe-red-42` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a lot of people are missing that feature but the super product attributes have a drag and drop feature.

Using it, you can change the order of the product attributes and after clicking **Save and Continue Edit** it will use the new order when generating the child product skus.

To use the drag and drop, just click the orange double arrow next to the attribute, and you can reorder your attributes.

[image]